# Creating divs for image gallery. 2 columns, 1 column, 2 columns, and so on

Tags: html, css

Here's the sample image for the type of divs that I am trying to create:

https://postimg.org/image/9in5skhbp/

The single column div would hold a landscape image, the 2 column divs would hold a portrait image each. What's the easiest way to implement this without using a table for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can set the width of your images and want to keep it very simple you can do the following:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  clear: left;
}

.inline-img {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x100">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x100">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x400" class="inline-img">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x400" class="inline-img">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x100">
```